# Woocommerce auto select attributes dropdown values in loopproducts

Tags: jquery, loops, variables, woocommerce

I am trying to create a dropdown for a specific category loop page and on selecting the size from dropdown the attributes dropdown from variable products should change automatically for the category products.
I tried the loop and with javascript i changed the elementid to do this. But it only takes effect on the first product in the loop.

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'product_cat' => 'boxers',
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setSelectValue (id, val) {
document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
setSelectValue('pa_size', 'small');
</script>

<?php
echo "boxers";
```